# How destroy a php session after variable is shown

Tags: php

i have 2 php page,
First page ;

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["firstname"] = "Peter";
  $_SESSION["lastname"] = "Parker";

  header('Location: http://quebecprohockeyleague.com/simulation/team/training');
```

Seconde Page ;

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
  if (isset($_SESSION["firstname"])) {
    echo 'Hi, ' . $_SESSION["firstname"] . ' ' . $_SESSION["lastname"];
    session_destroy();
  }
```

The problem is when i remove session_destroy(); the text show everytime, and when session_destroy(); is there, the text dont show at all.

I want to destroy the session after the text is show ? it is possible ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `unset($_SESSION);` works ...

Comment: I think iv try it, and give me the same result, show me the text when is not there, and always show me the text when is there

Comment: just retry it and didnt work, the text show up when i leave the page and comeback

Comment: You aren't being very clear what is happening, with steps, and what you expect to happen. If you unset the session after you display it (with destroy or unset), it will not show up again unless you are setting it again before displaying it. For example if you are going to page 1 all the time, of course its going to show since that page always sets the values. And if you destroy things before you echo them, of course they will not show up.

Comment: I have 2 page, First page send information to the script page, the seconde return session information, to the first page.
I want the session to be deleted, after the person leave the page. When i use destroy_session(); the data of the session is not shown.
I want the page show the session information then destroy the session.

Comment: Because right now my problem is when i leave the page and comeback on it, The last session information is there.
Ps : Sorry for the english, im french so its not my first language

Comment: The only thing i get this working if made a script that only show the text if my trigger counter is equal at 1

Answer (score 0):

store session value in a variable before showing the data and then destroy the session after that you can use that varaible to print the value

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but this doesnt work either...
Its like session_destroy(); its primary and bypass anything